# Want entry as root at login screen to do backups via deja-dup gui

Tags: login, backup, root

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I open Deja Dup as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130674/how-do-i-open-deja-dup-as-root)

I want to use the deja-dup gui to backup (the one with the black safe icon).  I prefer to do this as root user, not as a normal user.   When I enter *root* as username in Login screen and the correct password, the cursor just spins and won't let me in.

I can't recall whether this happened before.  Is there something new in Precise that prevents this.  I am fully aware of super user security issues, but I think backups should be done as root.