# What's the best way to resolve "read permission" error when including /etc in backup?

Tags: backup, sudo, etc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I open Deja Dup as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130674/how-do-i-open-deja-dup-as-root)

Running Ubuntu 12.04 and using the built in Backup utility (Deja-dup) to back up `/home` and `/etc` every night.

Some files in `/etc` fail with `read permission` error because, well, obviously Backup runs under my user account and I don't have permission to read them.

I used to do this on 11.10 and it worked pretty well; saved my bacon a couple of times.

What's the best way to reconfig so `/etc` backups run successfully? Obviously I don't want to grant my user account read access to a bunch of files that are off-limits for a reason. Is there a good way to get Backup to sudo instead of running as me? Is there an easy way to set up a different job under root to back up `/etc` and invoke it with at `/cron`?

Comment: The question may vary in how it was asked, but the answer is near identical