# How can I backup files on /etc using Deja Dup?

Tags: root, deja-dup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I open Deja Dup as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130674/how-do-i-open-deja-dup-as-root)

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I'm trying to setup Deja Dup to backup the files for several users (/home) and /etc but as it runs as myself, there are many files it cannot read and therefore cannot backup.

I want to try running Deja Dup as root as then it should be able to read and backup all files.

I've seen some other info about how to set up a particular App to run as root, so I guess I should try that.

Comment: Thanks jokerdino, very helpful. I'll try that. I assume I should keep my user backups in a different folder to the root backups?

Comment: My backup when run as root (to a different folder than my backup run not as root) worked with no errors, so now I'm happy! Many Thanks! How do I flag this question as answered? It doesn't say how in the Ask Ubuntu faq, or are questions only closed if they are inappropriate?

Comment: Good to know that it worked without any problems. And don't worry about closing this question. It will be handled.

Answer (score 2):

To Enable root login, open Terminal and enter following commands:

```
sudo passwd root
sudo sh -c 'echo "greeter-show-manual-login=true" >> /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf'
```

Now Restart your lightdm and login as root.

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

[image]

Comment: you are welcome if this solve your problem mark as accept to help others

Answer (score 1):

Once you've unlocked the root account, you have to edit `/etc/lightdm/users.conf` and change `minimum-uid` to 0.

Comment: Thanks sly. As it seems the accepted thing to do is not login as root, and I no longer need to thanks to jokerdino's help, I won't use this unless I need to in future.

Comment: No problem. Just providing the answer for other people that may have this question.