# Problems running Deja Dup with elevated priveleges

Tags: 12.04, backup, root, deja-dup, gksu

As advised by [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/130702/101348), I'm using

```
gksu deja-dup-preferences
```

and

```
gksu "deja-dup --backup"
```

to backup my data, including files that have root-only permissions on them.

Both of the two ways lead to the same two problems as perceived in comparison to how Deja Dup regularly works.

1. No report appears after backup is finished. Regular Deja Dup used to bring up a notification, saying that backup is complete, but not in this case.
2. Deja Dup run with elevated privileges does not memorize either my Amazon S3 secret access key or the encryption password, I have to reenter them over and over again. Running `deja-dup --backup` in the regular mode always used to apply the passwords from the last successful backup provided that backup destinations match (I had "Remember password" option turned on in all cases, of course). Hence, I'm not certain if automatic backup is going to work if enable it for the root mode Deja Dup and it's gonna take about 2 days to check it.

Comment: Where is your secret access key? In what directory?

Comment: @ZDroid The Amazon S3 "secret access key" is not a file, it's a string of characters akin to a password.

Comment: You need a file to store keys. :P

Comment: @ZDroid Are you sure you know what you are talking about?

Comment: Yes. All of your keys than you need to copy is in any1 file.

Comment: @ZDroid If so, would you like to make an answer from that?

Comment: I don't know where is your key. :D Maybe is answer for you this - **your secret access key is in /home/you, not in /root. When you run backup that maybe ignore keys for your /home**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`deja-dup` uses gnome-keyring<sup>[1](https://live.gnome.org/DejaDup/HowItWorks)</sup><sup>,[2](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeKeyring)</sup> to remember your passwords and keys. So you need to again save your password when running as root, because your earlier setting won't be used in this case.