# Graying and ungraying deja dup restore button

Tags: backup, restore, deja-dup

I use deja dup on a daily backup cycle. But when I call up its GUI, the restore button is grayed out. The work around I use to get the restore button active is to go to System Monitor and kill the deja dup process. After doing this the button is active (usable). 
This is a pretty kludgey way to solve the problem and I'm wondering if there is a configuration setting (or something else) that will permanently achieve the same effect. Many thnnks for any help.

Comment: Has nobody else experienced this problem? I'd be surprised if that were true.

Comment: I just had the same issue. Backup and Restore buttons and grayed out. 
It turns out there was an issue after, with my previous backup, some hidden dir didn't pack. So Deja dup open a secondary dialog to inform me. This small popup did not show on the screen, it was minimized under a bunch of other windows I opened. Closing that pop up (in your case, killing all instants of the program) solved the issue.

Comment: I have no secondary dialog. Even on a fresh start (at least after a backup runs the restore button is greyed out). Not yet checked if its available after a reboot but before a backup runs. In any case, the only thing here that worked was killing the program as specified above. This *should* be a problem with the program as a well working program should not do that.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem using Ubuntu Backup. I think it is due to the fact that you did not run the program as the root user.

On the command line type:

```
gksu deja-dup --restore
```

Remind `gksu` is important. It brings up the GUI restore dialog and then you can restore all the files.

See more here: [How do I open Deja Dup as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130674/how-do-i-open-deja-dup-as-root)

Comment: Didn't work for me. It just starts a new clean deja dup that doesn't know about my backup location which also can't be selected.