# Backup erros on Xenial

Tags: 16.04

Roughly translated from my localized UI, I get such errors when using the build-in backup utility:

```
Permission denied while creating  „/duplicity-full.20160503T030844Z.vol1.difftar.gpg”.
```

Anyone was this? It's on an Asus UX32VD, using the internal 24GB SSD as the backup location.

The location I try to back up to:

```
 ls -la /media/gabor/7e5a3dad-e7f9-4db4-ade5-7dac70379c6e/
 drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Apr 29 00:50 .
 drwxr-x---+ 3 root root  4096 May  2 20:00 ..
 drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 16384 Apr 29 00:50 lost+found
```

Comment: well its a permission issue of course ... I would check the permissions on the folder where duplicity-full is trying to be written to.   .. maybe add in your question where the storage folder is located and what the permissions / owner / user is for that folder.

Comment: ok .. so it is a drive on its own ... hmm lol .. I know how to set permissions on a folder and files but ... not real sure on a drive... basically it seems like the drive only has root access so the  program can't access it to create any files on it. I have never used the built in backup ... can you launch it as root?

Comment: thanks for the tips, this solved it: http://askubuntu.com/a/130702/149354

Comment: yeah gksu is running it as root which gives it access to write  to that drive .. glad  you found what you needed :D