# How do I open/configure/run Deja Dup as root in Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: permissions, 17.10, root, gui, deja-dup

Trying to backup my System using Deja Dup I receive errors about files my normal user can not access. To backup my System I need to configure and later run DejaDup as root.

I know a similar question exists here [How do I open Deja Dup as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130674/how-do-i-open-deja-dup-as-root)
but the solutions do not work in Ubuntu 17.10. for me.

When trying to `gksu deja-dup-preferences` as suggested by @Jakob or following the detailed explanation of Fran, I get the Errormessage:

"Unable to copy the user's Xauthorization file."

Further reading about [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w) teaches me, that this is Ubuntu 17.10. new feature not to allow GUIs as root.
I wonder what would be the best practice to get to run DejaDup as root in such a way that I can configure the backup settings and then start the backup-process. Any suggestions or ideas would be kindly appreciated. Thx.