# Backup: Could not restore the following files. Please make sure you are able to write to them

Tags: backup, deja-dup

Every time I do my weekly backup, I get the following error:

" Could not restore the following files. Please make sure you are able to write to them."

and shows then these files:

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Starbucks-Clientes.nmconnection
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Telekom.nmconnection
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/VuelingWi-Fi.nmconnection
/etc/at.deny
/etc/cups/classes.conf
/etc/cups/ppd/HP-Color-LaserJet-CP4520-Series.ppd
/etc/cups/ppd/HP-LaserJet-400-color-M451dn.ppd
/etc/cups/ppd/HP-LaserJet-P4014.ppd
/etc/cups/ppd/HP_LaserJet_P4014_1A9561_.ppd
/etc/cups/printers.conf
/etc/cups/printers.conf.O
/etc/cups/ssl
/etc/cups/subscriptions.conf
/etc/cups/subscriptions.conf.O
/etc/sudoers
/etc/sudoers.d/README
```

I've seen other posts about this problem but none solve the issue that is specific to my problem. I am not trying to restore or do anything like that. I'm just doing a backup.

Comment: Try opening Deja Dup backup tool manually every week from the command line as super user (then you should be able to backup the files that need super user permissions, such as /etc/sudoers.d) Run `sudo deja-dup`

Comment: This may also help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/130674/how-do-i-open-deja-dup-as-root

Comment: Deja-dup isn't really designed to back up system files like the ones in /etc when run by a standard user. It's more for backing up your home directory. If you want a successful backup of /etc, you will need to run deja-dup using sudo. Consider using Timeshift to back up your system, and restrict the use of deja-dup to backing up your data.

Comment: I tried running it as sudo a few weeks ago but that doesnt really work well. Ill try Timeshift